# Responsive asynchronous search-as-you-type in Java 8

Tags: java-8, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, responsiveness

I'm trying to implement a "search as you type" pattern in Java.

The goal of the design is that no change gets lost but at the same time, the (time consuming) search operation should be able to abort early and try with the updated pattern.

Here is what I've come up so far (Java 8 pseudocode):

```
AtomicReference<String> patternRef
AtomicLong modificationCount
ReentrantLock busy;
Consumer<List<ResultType>> resultConsumer;

// This is called in a background thread every time the user presses a key
void search(String pattern) {
    // Update the pattern
    synchronized {
        patternRef.set(pattern)
        modificationCount.inc()
    }

    try {
        if (!busy.tryLock()) {
            // Another search is already running, let it handle the change
            return;
        }

        // Get local copy of the pattern and modCount
        synchronized {
            String patternCopy = patternRef.get();
            long modCount = modificationCount.get()
        }

        while (true) {
            // Try the search. It will return false when modificationCount changes before the search is finished
            boolean success = doSearch(patternCopy, modCount)
            if (success) {
                // Search completed before modCount was changed again
                break
            }

            // Try again with new pattern+modCount
            synchronized {
                patternCopy = patternRef.get();
                modCount = modificationCount.get()
            }
        }
    } finally {
        busy.unlock();
    }
}

boolean doSearch(String pattern, long modCount)

    ... search database ...
    if (modCount != modificationCount.get()) {
        return false;
    }

    ... prepare results ...
    if (modCount != modificationCount.get()) {
        return false;
    }

    resultConsumer.accept(result); // Consumer for the UI code to do something

    return modCount == modificationCount.get();
}
```

Did I miss some important point? A race condition or something similar?

Is there something in Java 8 which would make the code above more simple?

Comment: Are the three ```synchronized``` necessary?

Comment: That’s so overly complicated that I do not even want to think about whether there are race conditions or not. Why use an `AtomicReference<String>` when all access to that variable happens inside a `synchronized` block? Likewise the `modificationCount` could be a `volatile` variable instead, but in the end, the `modificationCount` is entirely obsolete as just checking whether the used pattern is equal to the current pattern would be enough. Further, whoever triggered the background invocation of `search`, i.e. the event handling thread, should do the check already, then you don’t need a lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem of this code can be summarized as “trying to achieve atomicity by *multiple* distinct atomic constructs”. The combination of multiple atomic constructs is not atomic and trying to reestablish atomicity leads to very complicated, usually broken, and inefficient code.

In your case, `doSearch`’s last check `modCount == modificationCount.get()` happens while still holding the lock. After that, another thread (or multiple other threads) could update the search string and mod count, followed by finding the lock occupied, hence, concluding that another search is running and will take care.

But that thread doesn’t care after that last `modCount == modificationCount.get()` check. The caller just does `if (success) { break; }`, followed by the `finally { busy.unlock(); }` and returns.

So the answer is, yes, you have potential race conditions.

---

So, instead of settling on two atomic variables, `synchronized` blocks, and a `ReentrantLock`, you should use one atomic construct, e.g. a single atomic variable:

```java
final AtomicReference<String> patternRef = new AtomicReference<>();
Consumer<List<ResultType>> resultConsumer;

// This is called in a background thread every time the user presses a key
void search(String pattern) {
    if(patternRef.getAndSet(pattern) != null) return;
    // Try the search. doSearch will return false when not completed
    while(!doSearch(pattern) || !patternRef.compareAndSet(pattern, null))
        pattern = patternRef.get();
}

boolean doSearch(String pattern) {
    //... search database ...
    if(pattern != (Object)patternRef.get()) {
        return false;
    }

    //... prepare results ...
    if(pattern != (Object)patternRef.get()) {
        return false;
    }

    resultConsumer.accept(result); // Consumer for the UI code to do something

    return true;
}
```

Here, a value of `null` indicates that no search is running, so if a background thread sets this to a non-`null` value and finds the old value to be `null` (in an atomic operation), it knows it has to perform the actual search. After the search, it tries to set the reference to `null` again, using `compareAndSet` with the pattern used for the search. Thus, it can only succeed if it has not changed again. Otherwise, it will fetch the new value and repeat.

These two atomic updates are already sufficient to ensure that there is only a single search operation at a time while not missing an updated search pattern. The ability of `doSearch` to return early when it detects a change, is just a nice to have and not required by the caller’s loop.

Note that in this example, the check within `doSearch` has been reduced to a reference comparison (using a cast to `Object` to prevent compiler warnings), to demonstrate that it can be as cheap as the `int` comparison of your original approach. As long as no new string has been set, the reference will be the same.

But, in fact, you could also use a string comparison, i.e. `if(!pattern.equals(patternRef.get())) { return false; }` without a significant performance degradation. String comparison is not (necessarily) expensive in Java. The first thing, the implementation of `String`’s `equals` does, is a reference comparison. So if the string has not changed, it will return `true` immediately here. Otherwise, it will check the lengths then (unlike C strings, the length is known beforehand) and return `false` immediately on a mismatch. So in the typical scenario of the user typing another character or pressing backspace, the lengths will differ and the comparison bail out immediately.

Comment: Very good points. I started with the modCount and then the design went from there. Your comments make me wonder if the return value of doSearch() has much merit anymore. It only shortcuts the compareAndSet(). We'll see after I've written the unit tests for the code.

Comment: Yes, the return value only shortcuts the `compareAndSet()`, but this also allows to write a simple pre-test loop which will only invoke `pattern = patternRef.get();` when necessary. Having a `void doSearch()` would make the caller more complicated. There could be other hypothetical advantages if you re-use the method at other places.